# How to handle source code with dependencies to different versions of JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I don't use JUnit, but I have two bodies of imported source code from different libraries and both use JUnit; however, they seem to be using a different version.

For example, one imports things like `junit.runner...` and the other has `org.junit.runners...`.

I read a little bit of the JUnit documentation and it appears that they do not follow a strict backward compatibility principle and different versions apparently have different features and require different code, so there would appear to be no simple way to "upgrade" one of my libraries to the latest version.

How do I deal with this incompatibility? (other than just throw out all the tests which I am half inclined to do)

Comment: I was under the impression that JUnit is pretty good about backward compatibility.  Have you actually tried placing only the latest version in your classpath and seeing whether any problems occur?

Comment: @NathanHughes I am using source code, not bundled jars. I can't put two different files with the same name "junit.jar" in the same folder (my lib folder). Right now, I have a junit.jar lib that only works with one set of source code, but the other set is failing to compile. If I rename the jars, so if I had say a junit3.jar and a junit4.jar, then I can still potentially have a problem with name conflicts if the two different jars expose the same package structure.

Answer (score 1):

Junit 3 and junit 4 use separate package hierarchies, junit.framework for 3 and org.junit for 4. Tests utilizing these different versions  should be able to coexist. There could be problems with other libraries if the code based are using different versions of the same mock libraries or helpers like  Hamcrest. I would be very hesitant to combine these.

Keep these two bodies of code in separate projects and let each of them run their own tests with their own version of junit. Then you can write a script that combines the two sets of classes into one jar, use uberjar, or whatever. Check out the available plugins for whatever build tool you're using.

Especially if you're modifying somebody else's code, discarding the tests seems reckless. Even if they don't seem to provide much value they're better than nothing and you can improve them gradually.

Comment: I considered this, but I was hoping to avoid the complexity of separate projects. I want to have everything in a single project. I use IntelliJ BTW.

Answer (score 1):

The point of unit tests is to help you find and fix bugs in **your** delivery.

So ask yourself: "Do you intend to run those tests? To then fix that 3rd party code?"

Most likely, the answer is "no". (and it should be "no" in my eyes).

Thus: follow your intuition and go for *just throw out all the tests*.

Beyond that: those are unit tests. Supposed to be run by the people delivering that 3rd party code. What do you expect to find when running their tests on their source code? Meaning: if those folks are shipping deliveries where unit tests break; then you should consider not using that product in the first place.

And continuing on that thought: JUnit4 is out for many years. That would mean: you are using a product where people stopped making updates to their unit test setup probably many years ago - another reason to question the "value" of the library behind that!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put different jars for JUnit 3 (`junit.runner`) and JUnit 4 (`org.junit.runners`) into your classpath. The JUnit4 jar contains the JUnit 3 classes, too. You can use it to run JUnit 3 **and** JUnit 4 tests.